# Is there a ManyEyes API?

Tags: visualization, data-visualization, google-visualization

I can't find one. But I find it hard to believe they've built the service without an API. Can it be true?

If so, can anyone suggest an alternative, other than the Google Charts API?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't believe there is.  Do you only want charts or do you want a specific visualization.  There are lots of charting libraries you could use.  There are also lots visualization libraries.  What specific visualizations are you interested in, and what language/platform are you interested in?

Comment: Really I'd like something language-agnostic, that I can just feed data, as one does with the Google Charts API. I'd like a wide range of charts - as wide as possible!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Swivel](http://www.swivel.com/) has [a charts api](http://wiki.github.com/swivel/api/chart-api).  [Yahoo](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/charts/) also does.  You could use [CEwolf](http://cewolf.sourceforge.net/new/index.html) and set up your own api.  It wouldn't be hard to set up a rest api for accessing the charts.

**Edit:**

Here are some other links that might be useful

- [Simple css solution for bar charts](http://ajaxian.com/archives/pure-css-bar-charts-as-a-simple-api)
- [Protovis](http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/) makes it easy to create chart in Javascript
- [Another simple charting solution](http://ajaxian.com/archives/highcharts-really-nice-charting-api)

**Edit:**

ManyEyes has the ability to [show ManyEyes visualizations on your own web site](http://manyeyes.alphaworks.ibm.com/blog/2007/12/12/embeddable-visualizations-have-arrived/), but  [from this web page](http://manyeyes.alphaworks.ibm.com/blog/2008/11/21/many-eyes-on-rails/) it's obvious that ManyEyes did not have an api in 2008.  If you think about it, IBM is a services company.  They make money selling services to you, not giving you free access to their services.  I'm sure it would be possible to pay IBM for access to ManyEyes, [as the New York Times probably did](http://flowingdata.com/2008/10/28/new-york-times-visualization-lab-collaboration-with-many-eyes/).  On the other hand, Google, Yahoo, and others make money by bringing people to their web site, so they are more likely to give things like this away for free.